# Opening GeoJSON style properties in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geojson

I constructed a GeoJSON file (exemple below) that works fine with http://geojson.io. This GeoJSON file has style properties e.g. 'fill' (hex colour) and 'fill-opacity'. They appear on geojson.io but when I open the file in QGIS 3.10 by adding a vector layer, the colours properties don't show.

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection", "features": [
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[4.904782,46.160867],[4.932978,46.183458],[4.958471,46.153297],[4.926307,46.119968],[4.909106,46.129304],[4.903015,46.157966],[4.904782,46.160867]]]},"properties":{"code":"01001","densite":48.9,"fill":"#33a7c2","fill-opacity":0.5,"nom":"L'Abergement-Clémenciat","population":767,"stroke-width":0,"surface":15.7},"id":"0"},
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[5.404077,46.007933],[5.426148,46.030981],[5.441272,46.025699],[5.444129,46.017196],[5.431219,45.983352],[5.424755,45.986633],[5.404077,46.007933]]]},"properties":{"code":"01002","densite":26.7,"fill":"#40b5c4","fill-opacity":0.5,"nom":"L'Abergement-de-Varey","population":243,"stroke-width":0,"surface":9.1},"id":"1"},
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[5.327218,45.956848],[5.33756,45.984154],[5.347269,45.982477],[5.397014,45.981931],[5.413537,45.978836],[5.408842,45.942285],[5.386062,45.930905],[5.341149,45.948446],[5.327218,45.956848]]]},"properties":{"code":"01004","densite":574.7,"fill":"#2259a6","fill-opacity":0.5,"nom":"Ambérieu-en-Bugey","population":14081,"stroke-width":0,"surface":24.5},"id":"2"},
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[4.886433,46.016032],[4.909751,46.01918],[4.947804,46.000368],[4.942665,45.979454],[4.927599,45.979931],[4.89574,45.979919],[4.88082,45.985732],[4.886433,46.016032]]]},"properties":{"code":"01005","densite":104.4,"fill":"#1f93c0","fill-opacity":0.5,"nom":"Ambérieux-en-Dombes","population":1671,"stroke-width":0,"surface":16},"id":"3"},
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[5.570681,45.753687],[5.58358,45.762878],[5.590151,45.760441],[5.611119,45.749335],[5.614595,45.734707],[5.581117,45.740454],[5.570681,45.753687]]]},"properties":{"code":"01006","densite":18.3,"fill":"#55bec1","fill-opacity":0.5,"nom":"Ambléon","population":110,"stroke-width":0,"surface":6},"id":"4"},
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[5.299163,45.997168],[5.31167,46.025402],[5.324878,46.041649],[5.334895,46.037575],[5.404077,46.007933],[5.424755,45.986633],[5.413537,45.978836],[5.397014,45.981931],[5.359756,45.995581],[5.347269,45.982477],[5.33756,45.984154],[5.299163,45.997168]]]},"properties":{"code":"01007","densite":79.9,"fill":"#289cc1","fill-opacity":0.5,"nom":"Ambronay","population":2684,"stroke-width":0,"surface":33.6},"id":"5"},
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[5.309871,45.942847],[5.34196,45.945042],[5.361923,45.937116],[5.322747,45.922551],[5.309871,45.942847]]]},"properties":{"code":"01008","densite":144.2,"fill":"#1e88bc","fill-opacity":0.5,"nom":"Ambutrix","population":750,"stroke-width":0,"surface":5.2},"id":"6"},
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[5.642366,45.807903],[5.662188,45.776358],[5.656838,45.760535],[5.64793,45.763158],[5.646657,45.771722],[5.642366,45.807903]]]},"properties":{"code":"01009","densite":48,"fill":"#33a7c2","fill-opacity":0.5,"nom":"Andert-et-Condon","population":336,"stroke-width":0,"surface":7},"id":"7"},
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[5.759821,45.889161],[5.766034,45.936107],[5.816108,45.936625],[5.828334,45.938518],[5.815207,45.87666],[5.759821,45.889161]]]},"properties":{"code":"01010","densite":38,"fill":"#39adc3","fill-opacity":0.5,"nom":"Anglefort","population":1124,"stroke-width":0,"surface":29.6},"id":"8"},
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[5.641231,46.216895],[5.645631,46.22045],[5.661482,46.230984],[5.693443,46.22128],[5.643649,46.177811],[5.634104,46.179186],[5.635595,46.184271],[5.641231,46.216895]]]},"properties":{"code":"01011","densite":25.5,"fill":"#46b8c3","fill-opacity":0.5,"nom":"Apremont","population":383,"stroke-width":0,"surface":15},"id":"9"},
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[5.473186,45.989872],[5.483332,46.020687],[5.517273,46.023749],[5.550525,46.01624],[5.554992,46.005325],[5.522918,45.983055],[5.481082,45.970653],[5.473186,45.989872]]]},"properties":{"code":"01012","densite":15,"fill":"#59bfc0","fill-opacity":0.5,"nom":"Aranc","population":326,"stroke-width":0,"surface":21.7},"id":"10"},
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[5.464421,45.914082],[5.474257,45.919993],[5.490901,45.913944],[5.525779,45.890373],[5.525134,45.863399],[5.512397,45.855919],[5.464421,45.914082]]]},"properties":{"code":"01013","densite":10.5,"fill":"#6dc6be","fill-opacity":0.5,"nom":"Arandas","population":148,"stroke-width":0,"surface":14.1},"id":"11"},
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[5.659473,46.2918],[5.684926,46.31082],[5.725034,46.261067],[5.714583,46.256425],[5.659473,46.2918]]]},"properties":{"code":"01014","densite":142.6,"fill":"#1e88bc","fill-opacity":0.5,"nom":"Arbent","population":3379,"stroke-width":0,"surface":23.7},"id":"12"},
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[5.604925,45.708015],[5.623456,45.719947],[5.640689,45.747767],[5.64793,45.763158],[5.656838,45.760535],[5.676472,45.708344],[5.676312,45.696625],[5.661048,45.694019],[5.617312,45.674177],[5.604925,45.708015]]]},"properties":{"code":"01015","densite":28.3,"fill":"#40b5c4","fill-opacity":0.5,"nom":"Arboys en Bugey","population":640,"stroke-width":0,"surface":22.6},"id":"13"},
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[4.914201,46.481352],[4.929086,46.504022],[5.006992,46.477989],[5.006579,46.461765],[4.989191,46.459813],[4.914201,46.481352]]]},"properties":{"code":"01016","densite":26.4,"fill":"#40b5c4","fill-opacity":0.5,"nom":"Arbigny","population":462,"stroke-width":0,"surface":17.5},"id":"14"},
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[5.465818,45.950228],[5.489177,45.947562],[5.501823,45.940984],[5.490901,45.913944],[5.474257,45.919993],[5.465818,45.950228]]]},"properties":{"code":"01017","densite":56.2,"fill":"#2fa4c2","fill-opacity":0.5,"nom":"Argis","population":438,"stroke-width":0,"surface":7.8},"id":"15"},
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[5.558633,45.865141],[5.593227,45.862867],[5.612849,45.853302],[5.609256,45.848315],[5.573841,45.845877],[5.558633,45.865141]]]},"properties":{"code":"01019","densite":3.8,"fill":"#9ed9b8","fill-opacity":0.5,"nom":"Armix","population":26,"stroke-width":0,"surface":6.9},"id":"16"},
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[4.801092,46.001306],[4.801745,46.007185],[4.808435,46.007398],[4.822385,46.004403],[4.837319,45.973237],[4.801092,46.001306]]]},"properties":{"code":"01021","densite":248,"fill":"#1f78b4","fill-opacity":0.5,"nom":"Ars-sur-Formans","population":1389,"stroke-width":0,"surface":5.6},"id":"17"},
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[5.703578,45.874708],[5.704561,45.861516],[5.696419,45.861517],[5.678995,45.862864],[5.703578,45.874708]]]},"properties":{"code":"01022","densite":371.8,"fill":"#2168ad","fill-opacity":0.5,"nom":"Artemare","population":1227,"stroke-width":0,"surface":3.3},"id":"18"},
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[4.865908,46.375624],[4.887947,46.402769],[4.897991,46.399032],[4.896086,46.384523],[4.876317,46.369452],[4.865908,46.375624]]]},"properties":{"code":"01023","densite":13.4,"fill":"#5fc1c0","fill-opacity":0.5,"nom":"Asnières-sur-Saône","population":63,"stroke-width":0,"surface":4.7},"id":"19"},
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[5.148056,46.298647],[5.219786,46.315016],[5.217267,46.292878],[5.16267,46.255984],[5.150862,46.275507],[5.148056,46.298647]]]},"properties":{"code":"01024","densite":173,"fill":"#1e83ba","fill-opacity":0.5,"nom":"Attignat","population":3270,"stroke-width":0,"surface":18.9},"id":"20"}
]}
```

Comment: If you also seek a Python solution then please ask for that ina separate question and include a code snippet that illustrates what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: It was just to say that I am open to any kind of solution, that would involve or not coding.

Comment: We try to separate GUI from coding questions. Please use this question for seeking a non-coding (GUI) solution. You can always ask a coding question separately.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you have to use data defined overrides for that, see picture below

[image]

if you want to take the opacity field in count, we have to change the data defined override and use an expression to put the separate opacity and color fields together. QGIS is expecting the opacity information within the color value as an alpha value between 0 and 100. The expression then would be:

```
set_color_part( "fill",'alpha', "fill-opacity" *100)
```

in the data defined override dialog select "edit" and enter the expression:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! One more question, how to apply the 'fill-opacity' settings of the file ?

Comment: See my edited answer above...

Answer (score 1):

A little change and it worked for me.

```
set_color_part( "fill",'alpha', to_int(255*"fill-opacity"))
```